# after fork(),why does the local variable which stored a malloc char**returned from another function present nothing?

Tags: c, linux, unix

I wrote a little programe for learning `fork()`, here is the problem.

```
int main()
{
    char **str = NULL;
    int pid;

    str = get_command();

    printf("befork fork(), str[0] = %s, str[1] = %s\n", str[0], str[1]);

    if((pid = fork()) == 0)
    {
        printf("str[0] = %s, str[1] = %s\n", str[0], str[1]);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("str[0] = %s, str[1] = %s\n", str[0], str[1]);
    }
}
char **get_command()
{
    char *cmd[2];
    cmd[0] = malloc(6);
    memcpy(cmd[0], "hello\0", 6);

    cmd[1] = malloc(6);
    memcpy(cmd[1], "world\0", 6);

    return cmd;
}
```

In `get_command()` function,I define a `char *cmd[2]` and then `malloc` two strings for the two elements of cmd.Before fork(),the str can be printed as expected.But after `fork(),`the `str` been printed in parent and child process are both NULL. Why?

Comment: Show the implementation of `get_command`.

Comment: Show your code instead of describing it.

Comment: Debuggung 101: Check your assumptions (i.e., contents of `str` *after* `get_command()` and *before* `fork()`).

Comment: `return cmd;` your function returns the address of a local variable. (cmd is an array, but since arrays cannot be returnned as a whole, it decays into a pointer; which also corresponds to your function's return type)

Answer (score 0):

> In get_command() function,I define a char *cmd[2]

You should allocate some storage for the array as well

```
char **cmd;
cmd = malloc(2 * sizeof(char*));
```

otherwise it won't work.

If you just define it as `char *cmd[2];` in the body of a function, then it's a local variable, and its contents will be undefined after the function returns.